# UNIX: Viewing Disk Usage statistics with directories only

Tags: unix, du

I'm working on a script with a menu and a few options that you can select to perform actions. I am currently stuck on the last option, as it asks for you to calculate the Disk Usage statistics for all of the directories in your home directory in human-readable format.

I know what the command is for disk usage and the human-readable format, but I just need help listing just the names of the directories in the home directory. I'm hoping I can put those names into a variable to use with the DU command.

Any suggestions on how I can approach this problem?

Comment: `find /some/path -type d | xargs du -a | sort -nr | more`

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me the find command, I completely forgot about that. I was able to set a variable with the results of find -type d, and used a PATH for du -h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list the directories in the home directory using this line :
**ls /home/user -d */**
I don't really know why you need to put them in a variable, but piping them with du would be as easy as 
**ls /home/user -d */ | du -h**

Comment: That command is only showing the home directory, and not the other directories such as Documents. I was able to solve it with the help of the aarosil.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak the `find` options:

```
for i in $(find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d | tail -n+2); do 
    du -hs "$i"
done
```

You can use the `.` link as the total for home by removing the call to `tail`:

```
for i in $(find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d); do 
    du -hs "$i"
done
```

The easiest way to get both the `size` and `dir names` into a variable (or two) is to write the result of the `find/du -hs` command out to a temp file, then read the `size` and `dirnames` into either an **associative array** (BASH 4+) or read the `size` into an **indexed array** and read `dir names` into a second **indexed array** using the `read` command. This can be done by executing the code above in a subshell:

```
( for i in $(find "$HOME" -maxdepth 1 -type d | tail -n+2 ); do du -hs "$i"; done ) > tmpfile
```

Then simply `read` the contents of the `tmpfile` into your array of choice. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I was able to solve it with the help of another user. I just started UNIX a few weeks ago, so I wasn't able to pick up some of the information you shared in your comment. But it looks like the find command is something I overlooked.